# Haskell ghc main

Tags: haskell

I am trying to run a haskell script using ghc, however, compiler returns:

```
The function main is not defined in module Main
```

Any ideas why this is or what should I do to fix?

Cheers!

Comment: Um, supply the required 'main' method? What do you expect ghc to do?

Comment: Well, so far I've used WinHug which allows me to load a script and call individual functions... Nver heard of a 'main' module before

Comment: You should provide more details of what's in your script for people to have a good chance of working out what is causing your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ghc is a compiler, so needs a single entry point to run your code.
This is the `main` function, which should have type `IO ()` and live in your `Main` module (a module without a `module` declaration at the top is auto-named `Main`).

WinHugs is an interpreter - you can run any function you like with any arguments you like.
If you want to use ghc like that, you should use ghci instead - it's ghc's interpreter.

(WinHugs will *load* your code faster, and ghc will *run* your code faster.)

Comment: Compiler vs interpreter is unrelated to the existence of `Main`.

Answer (score 2):

To load the script and call functions in an interactive way, run `ghci`, and then type `:load MyScript.hs`.